# Whatever happened to the horses in Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-2011

In the first Thor movie we see Odin on Sleipnir. Loki, Thor, Lady Sif and the warriors three riding horses. He even went so far as to ask the cashier at the pet store for a horse (comic relief). But after that in the 2nd and 3rd movies we only see spaceships. Why is that?

[image: Warrior on a horse]

Comment: The most likely answer is that the writers forgot about this somewhat subtle detail, but it's probably unlikely that we will ever get any kind of verification.

Comment: In the movies, we've seen that Thor travels by Mjolnir around Asgard. He probably did this with Jane in Dark World. The reason why he didn't do it with the Warriors Three (and Sif & Loki) might simply be it would have been too awkward to travel to the Bifrost by Mjolnir with that many people.